# Jquery error in OnClick through PHP echo

Tags: php, jquery, variables, onclick

First some context, I have a very basic image carousel that displays video thumbnails I grabbed through a php foreach loop. When a user clicks on the thumbnail it loads the corresponding video into the above div. The carousel works great however the onclick event to send it to the div does not.

Okay I have the following line of code I want to execute and the code editor says its correct but when I run it in a browser i get a sytax error "Unexpected Token ," and the code doesn't end up working.

```
  echo "<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='setVideo(" .$youtube_link. "," .$type. "," .$video_title. "," .$custom_description. "," .$postURL. ");'>";
  print_thumbnail($featured_thumb,"thumbnail",$youtube_link);
  echo "</a></li>";
```

So I used the following code instead:

```
  echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="setVideo(\'' . $youtube_link . '\', \'yt\',\'' . $video_title . '\',\'' . $custom_description . '\',\'' . $postURL . '\' );">';
  print_thumbnail($featured_thumb,"thumbnail",$youtube_link);
  echo "</a></li>";
  } ?>
```

This code works and puts the video into the div but on certain video thumbnails when clicked it returns an "Unexpected identifier" error and doesn't work. I looked at the data being sent for each thumbnail and I didn't see any differences between each thumbnail to make it work on some but not others. The error is consistent as well and stays on the same posts each time. So my question is, is the error coming from JQuery or is it in the data being sent to JQuery.

This is the corresponding JQuery function.

```
  function setVideo(videoID, playerType, postTitle, postExcerpt, postURL ){
  width = 720;
  height = 405;
  if( playerType == 'yt' ) {
  $('#video_player').replaceWith("<iframe id='video_player' class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='"+ width +"' height='"+ height +"' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + "?hd=1&html5=1&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0' frameborder='0' ></iframe>");
   }
  }
```

Comment: Why did `$type` disappear from first to second code sample?

Comment: You replaced `$type` with `'yt'` and added an empty param `''` next to it. That means the function is getting one more parameter than it expects.

Comment: $type just contained yt so i just decided to type out yt in the onclick instead of using a variable.

Comment: No because the second ' is part of the concatenate for the PHP, the first one is the enclosing mark for the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out most of it. Using this code I noticed that the data coming into $custom_description contained a single quote ( ' ) that through off the jquery and hence gave the error.

```
 echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="setVideo(\'' . $youtube_link . '\', \'yt\',\'' . $video_title . '\',\'' . $custom_description . '\',\'' . $postURL . '\' );">';
  print_thumbnail($featured_thumb,"thumbnail",$youtube_link);
  echo "</a></li>";
  } ?>
```

I did a simple str_replace like so:

```
$string_desc = str_replace("'","\\'", $custom_description);
$string_title = str_replace("'","\\'", $video_title);

echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="setVideo(\'' . $youtube_link . '\', \'yt\', 
\'' . $string_title . '\',\'' . $string_desc . '\',\'' . $postURL . '\' );">';
print_thumbnail($featured_thumb,"thumbnail",$youtube_link); $video_title;
echo "</a></li>";
```

And everything works

Answer (score 0):

i have made a test with jqVideoBox and i have tested videos from youtube, metacafe, google and iFilm...

```
<a title="Youtube example." class="vidbox" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/NRH2jEyiiLo&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0"><img alt="Youtube" style="width: 130px;" src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/NRH2jEyiiLo/default.jpg"/></a>
<a title="Metacafe example." class="vidbox" href="http://www.metacafe.com/watch/386357/teach_magic_be_magician_money_magic/"><img alt="Metacafe" style="width: 130px;" src="http://images.metacafe.com/thumb/386357/2767198/4/catalog_top_item5/0/teach_magic_be_magician_money_magic.jpg"/></a>
<a title="Google Video example." class="vidbox" href="http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=1811233136844420765"><img alt="Google Video" style="width: 130px;" src="http://video.google.com/ThumbnailServer2?app=vss&amp;contentid=d53e613f82f74c96&amp;offsetms=50000&amp;itag=w160&amp;lang=en&amp;sigh=QGtXRNh3rW4hfa6DSQSFtfOimno"/></a>
<a title="iFilm example." class="vidbox" href="http://www.ifilm.com/video/2783985"><img alt="iFilm" style="width: 130px;" src="http://img4.ifilmpro.com/resize/image/stills/films/resize/istd/2783985.jpg?width=130"/></a>
```

and just call this function and the vids open!!

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    $(".vidbox").jqvideobox();
}
```

);

and i have imported 3 js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqvideobox.js"></script>
```

you can try this libs and see whats happen...

Comment: Thanks, I want to get this to work if possible I will try your code if indeed in the end mine doesn't work.